# On running my code is showing terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, codeblocks, bad-alloc

My code is an implementation of a graph in C++. I copied my code from a website, but when I try to run it on my local IDE, it is throwing an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#define pi 3.14159
#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
#define pf push_front

using namespace std;

class Graph{       // Graph class 
        int v;
        list <int> *l;
    public:
        Graph(int v)
        {
            this-> v = v;
            l = new list<int>[v];
        }
        void add_edge (int i , int j)
        {
            l[i].pb(j);
            l[j].pb(i);
        }
        void show_adj()
        {
            for(int i = 0  ; i < v ; i++)
                {
                cout << i << "->";
                for(int a : l[i])
            {
                cout << a << ",";
            }
            cout << "\n";
                }
        }
};

int main() // main body
{

    Graph g(4);
    g.add_edge(7,4);
    g.add_edge(7,3);
    g.add_edge(3,1);
    g.add_edge(4,1); // adding an edge
    g.show_adj(); //showing the edges
//vector<int> v;
//int t; cin >> t;
//while(t--)
//{
//
//}

return(0);
}
```

My code is showing

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'   what():  std::bad_alloc

I have gathered this has to do with a memory shortage, or variables falling out of the `main()` function, but I can not figure out how to address the problem in this specific situation. If it is relevant, I am working on a Windows computer.

Please help me to figure out what the problem is.

If you can post code snippets, it would be very easy for me.

Comment: First, you should not be using those awful macros such as `pb`, `ll`, etc.  Persons here have to read and understand your code, and using those macros do not help in this.  Second, tf you had used `std::vector<std::list<int>> l;` instead of `list <int>*l;`, and then `l.at(i).push_back(j);`, the error would be shown to you as a `std::out_of_range` exception.  It has nothing to do with a memory shortage.  These techniques of writing code that can do a self-diagnosis cannot be learned from whatever online competition coding website you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You create an array of lists with space for four lists and then try to set the value of the eighth entry. That won't work.

```
    Graph(int v)
    {
        this-> v = v;
        l = new list<int>[v];
    }

Graph g(4);
```

So, this means `g.l` has room for four lists numbered 0, 1, 2, and 3.

```
g.add_edge(7,4);

    void add_edge (int i , int j)
    {
        l[i].pb(j);
        l[j].pb(i);
    }
```

This tries to set the value of `l[7]`. But `l[3]` is the last element in `l`.

Also, are you sure you wanted an array of lists?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It actually worked . I am just learning graphs in cpp that's why I opted for this approach.